# GWT app and Hibernate under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, gwt, plugins

I have a GWT app created by GWT wizard under Eclipse. I also created a separate project (called Model) in the workspace where I put Hibernate classes and mapping hbm.xml files. Now I'd like to properly reference this project from my GWT project so that Hibernate configuration can successfuully load classes and mapping files from GWT service. I want to use Hibernate on server side to access database. After I specified that the Model project is referenced by GWT project the classes are visible from GWT service but while running the project GWT cannot see the hbm.xml files. How to properly configure the workspace?

Regards
Dominik

Comment: GWT is a client-side technology for the most part, and I'm assuming that you're trying to use Hibernate on the server?
Since GWT doesn't need to "see" your .hbm.xml files, I'm assuming that you're implying that when you load the GWT project in hosted/dev mode, the services you've written in the embedded server can't find your Hibernate configuration?  How are you loading Hibernate, and what error are you getting?

Comment: I solved the problem. I just copied hbm files to the same place where corresponding java classes are. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use the [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to build multimodule applications. To work with GWT I am using gwt-maven plugin. In eclipse I am using m2eclipse plugin. Hope it will help you.

P.S. I can't use more than one hyperlink, but you easy find these plugins by google.